# How can I apply 2 media queries in IE8 with respond JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, respond.js

All the code works fine in IE9+.

This works in IE8 using [respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond):

```
@media 
(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), 
(min-resolution: 192dpi) {
  // Code
}
```

This does not:

```
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (min-width: 700px), 
(min-resolution: 192dpi) and (min-width: 700px){
  // Code
}
```

Does anyone know another way to pass the media query to IE8?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I'm using respond.js. I guess this should be a JS tag

Comment: I updated answer with links to respond.js issues like yours. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Well, maybe i got it all wrong but you are specifying -webkit-stuff **AND** other width queries.

I don't believe ie will understant -webkit- but *can buggyly* understand min-resolution.

```
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (min-width: 700px), 
(min-resolution: 192dpi) and (min-width: 700px){
  // Code
}
```

By buggyly, i mean, all i found is not clear, and because you are using respond.js, it might be forced. I [found something on respond.js guihub](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond/issues/181) as a [duplication of this other issue](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond/issues/157)

To target IE8 only via media query :

```
@media \0screen {
    .your-css { background: blue; }
}
```

To exclude IE8 only use a condition comment :

```
<!--[if !IE 8]> 
   @media queries for all browsers except IE 8
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Yes, although the problem is that it is reading the query but only the `(min-width)` and not the `(min-device-ratio)`. Hence it's displaying content it shouldn't. Do you know a way simply to exlcude IE from the query?

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs because as Milky suggests, IE8 does not recognise `-webkit-`.

However, rather than ignoring the query completely, it still reads and applies the `min-width` query, thereby applying code that is meant for displays with higher resolution.

The fix is to exclude the `min-resolution` query from IE8 altogether.

http://browserhacks.com/ provides a great repo for this. The code I ended up using was:

```
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (min-width: @screen-md-min), 
(min-resolution: 192dpi) and (min-width: @screen-md-min){
    :root * > .selector { 
// code
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice. It will, on the other hand become overwelming if you have a lot off .declarations in your query scope to prefix with this fix. If this becomes the case, reconsider the conditional comment.